# Laravel route giving 500 error on a Specific Controller name

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I am using Laravel Framework version 4.2.17. I have made a new controller, model and Views on my localhost and after testing the code i uploaded them to live server.

For routes i am using laravel resources:

```
Route::resource('templates', 'EmailsController',['as' => 'admin']);
```

My controller is inside a folder i.e

> app->controllers->admin

File name is: EmailsController.php

Controller: `class EmailsController extends \AdminBaseController {...}`

Now if i access

> www.example.com/admin/templates

for this specific controller is am getting 500 error. If i change the route to other controller i.e

```
Route::resource('templates', 'JobsController',['as' => 'admin']);
```

the link

> www.example.com/admin/templates

shows me all job listing.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: is your JobsController extends AdminBaseController ?

Comment: What is the error? Turn on debugging, or look in /storage/logs for the error message. "500 error" means that the server had an error -- you need to find out what this error is.

Comment: @mcklayin yes the JobsController extends the AdminBaseController.

Answer (score 1):

After creating new controller.You need to do

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

on the terminal.This is necessary to know the laravel that the new controller is created.Mapping is done by composer.